# How to display notification alert from right side to left and hide after few second

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to display alert from the right side to left and after few second I want to hide that alert. Now alert coming from right to left but it does not start properly right side I mean the first time alert will hide and when to refresh the page it will come from the right side and I have to display 300px from right to left animate and hide after some second.
Would you help me in this?

```js
$(".success").fadeIn()
.css({left:400,position:'absolute'})
.animate({left:0}, 800, function() {
    // $('#selector').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow'); 
});
```

```css
div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
}


.success {
    background-color: #ddffdd;
    border-left: 6px solid #4CAF50;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="success">
  <p><strong>Success!</strong> Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your js code to:

```
showNotification();
setTimeout(hideNotification, 8000);

function showNotification() {
  $(".success")
    .fadeIn()
    .css({ right: 0, position: "absolute" })
    .animate({ left: 0 }, 1000, function() {
      // $('#selector').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
}

function hideNotification() {
  $(".success").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/mMGGJv)

Comment: Thanks for replying.Ofisora, It's working. I just need one information. How can I fit this notification after getting a success response from AJAX? any idea?

Comment: If it is working then you can accept/vote up the answer. Comments are not for extending or asking new questions. You can ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure, I will do that, I just need an idea about it

Comment: `success: function(data) {
               showNotification();
               setTimeout(hideNotification, 8000);
            }`, call the functions in success response.